# Get whatsapp media folder in android 10

Tags: whatsapp, android-10.0

I wrote code to fetch whatsapp media folder like below and
it works fine in android 9 and lower.

```
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator;
    File[] arrayOfFile = new File(root + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/").listFiles(fileParam -> {

        String fileName = fileParam.getName();
        return (fileName.endsWith(".mp4") || fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".png") || fileName.endsWith(".gif"));

    });
```

I know I should use Scoped Storage in android 10 to change the below code

```
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator;
```

But I don't know how to implement it.
please help me.
Thanks.